# What is the link between these countries?

Tags: pattern, geography

Last time, I was at the office when my friend John, who is a big fan of riddles and traveling, came up to me with a sly smile and a little piece of paper in his hands.

> "Hey, you like to hang around on PSE, right?
>
> -Yes, what do you want? You're afraid of introducing yourself on this website? Poor little thing.
>
> -Shut up already, and solve me this. What is the link between the countries written on that paper?
>
> -Oh, a puzzle? Nice, let me think a bit about it...
>
> -Just before you start, I can tell you that Germany and Morocco don't share the link either, but Slovenia does."

Here are the countries I found on the paper :

> Spain
>   Canada
>   Madagascar
>   Portugal
>   Namibia
>   Russia
>   Laos

**Can you help me to find the link between these countries?**

Edit *(I hope this edit and the new hint will narrow this puzzle. I will drop another one later)*: My friend John just contacted me, and told me that these countries also share the link :

> Belgium
>   France
>   Thailand
>   Senegal

He also told me that these ones **don't** share the link :

> Switzerland (talking about red and white...)
>   Denmark
>   Finland
>   Ireland

---

Hint (it has changed!) :

> My friend John and I are working in IT. You could say we are sort of webmasters, and we spend much time on the Internet.

Comment: *They all have an 'a' in their name.* Scratch that.

Comment: @tuskiomi "Germ**a**ny" does not share the link

Comment: No, but here's an interesting useless piece of information:
(From http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Madagascar)
"Madagascar"
large island off the east coast of Africa, from Mogadishu, the name of the city in Somalia, due to an error by Marco Polo in reading Arabic, whereby he thought the name was that of the island. There is no indigenous name for the whole island.

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, "Belgium" doesn't share it.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - 1. That does not stop Germany thwarting the "a" theory; and 2. Belgium was not there when I posted that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My goodness.

Each of these countries has

> A domain extension corresponding to an element on the periodic table.

These are as follows:

> Spain: .es (Einsteinium)
>  Canada: .ca (Calcium)
>  Madagascar: .mg (Magnesium)
>  Portugal: .pt (Platinum)
>  Namibia: .na (Sodium)
>  Russia: .ru (Ruthenium)
>  Laos: .la (Lanthanum)
>  Belgium: .be (Beryllium)
>  France: .fr (Francium)
>  Thailand: .th (Thorium)
>  Senegal: .sn (Tin)
>  Slovenia: .si (Silicon)

The countries that don't share the link are:

> Switzerland: .ch
>  Denmark: .dk
>  Finland: .fi
>  Ireland: .ie
>  Germany: .de
>  Morocco: .ma

Comment: Fulfill the answer with Slovenia, Germany and Morroco, +1

Comment: Well, we have a winner! I am curious about the "my goodness" at the beginning though :)...

Comment: Also, did the hint give too much away?

Comment: That hint seems to make it way easier but it could just be me seeing it after knowing the answer.

Answer (score 5):

They are all countries

> which have official names that, in their official language(s), end in a vowel sound

Like so:

> Spain - Spanish: Reino de España
>  Canada - English: Canada OR French: Canada, [ka.na.da]
>  Madagascar - French: République de Madagascar (silent r) OR Malagasy: Madagasikara
>  Portugal - Portuguese: República Portuguesa
>  Namibia - English: Republic of Namibia
>  Russia - Russian: Российская Федерация, "Rossijskaja Federacija"
>  Laos - Lao: ສາທາລະນະລັດ ປະຊາທິປະໄຕ ປະຊາຊົນລາວ (ວ is a long monophthong open-mid vowel)
>  Slovenia - Slovene: Slovenija, [slɔˈʋéːnija]
>  Gabon - French: République gabonaise
>
>  ...but not:
>  Germany - German: [ˈdɔʏtʃlant]
>  Morocco - Arabic: المغرب‎‎ al-Maghrib (ب is a bāʼ, pronounced "b") OR Berber: ⵍⵎⴰⵖⵔⵉⴱ (ⴱ also being a "b")

Comment: Not sure about Madagascar, but the rest looks really good

Comment: Oh, the only one I'm unsure of now is Gabon "...Gabonaise" is a nasal fricative I think. hmm

Comment: Well, I'm a native french speaker, and I can say that the r is not silent, just quiet :P. But I noticed afterword that you have malagasy up there too, so it's probably good to go.

Comment: ...that should say "voiced alveolar fricative", but I'm not sure if the "aise" ending is considered a vowel sound (there is a pathway in the mouth as we make it, so ...maybe?)

Comment: @dcfyj well we can ask Lord of dark about the "r" - but I reckon it ends in a sound made with an open pathway in the mouth - AKA a vowel sound.

Comment: As a native french speaker, I pronounce the 'r' at the end of Madagasar. And yes, Gabon doesn't make your list. Anyway, this is not the intended answer. I am going to modify a bit the original puzzle, add a couple of countries and a hint to narrow this

Answer (score 1):

A wrong answer, as one of the countries doesn't fit and the pattern also applies to Germany:

> Each of the countries contains two consecutive consonants in the alphabet:
>
>  Spain: N, P
>  Canada: C, D
>  Madagascar: R, S
>  Portugal: P, R
>  Namibia: M, N
>  Russia: R, S
>  Laos: ?
>
>  and, unfortunately, Germany: M, N, and Slovenia does not fit the pattern.

Comment: Not at all. Remember that Slovenia has to share the link also.

Comment: So, Pqortugal, then? ;)