# What is the link between these places?

Tags: knowledge, pattern

These places share a link:

> Berlin
> Budapest
> Catalonia
> Denmark
> France
> Italy
> London
> Scotland
> Sicily
> Switzerland
> Vienna

These places don’t:

> Andalusia
> Athens
> Belarus
> Croatia
> Cyprus
> Ljubljana
> Malta
> Oslo
> San Marino
> Sardinia
> Slovakia

What is the link?

---

Inspired by [What is the link between these countries?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/what-is-the-link-between-these-countries) but the solution is unrelated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one's pretty hard without very specialised expertise and/or computer help, but that's only fitting, since it seems that the linked places all have a more or less famous

> [chess opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_openings) named after them.

Can't find anything particular about the other list, maybe they're just a random collection of places that don't have that property?

Comment: Exactly right!!